# Problems with integrals, polar coordinates.

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I am having problems parameterizing these integrals:

$$\int_A{\frac{x}{1+x^2+y^2}}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$ for $A = \mathbb R^2 \bigcap \,\{y \ge 0\}$

and the volume of $M = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 : 0 \le y \le 1, \;  1 \le x^2 + z^2 \le 4,\; 0 \le z \le x\sqrt{3}  \}$

---

My attempt:

For $A$ I am using polar coordinates then $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\phi$ and $x=r \cos(\phi)$ where $r$ goes from $0$ to $+\infty$ and $\phi$ from $0$ to $\pi$.

For $M$ I don't think I can use polar coordinates so I would let $0 \le y \le 1,\;  1 \le x  \le \sqrt4,\;  0 \le z \le x\sqrt{3}$ and integrate $\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ in that order.

Comment: I think it's 1/6((Cylinder with height 1 and radius 2) - (Cylinder with height 1 and radius 1))=Pi/2. Yeah the area is strange. I didn't even try to solve it by integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one you did it right. Indeed, we have to evaluate: $$\int_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{r^2}{1+r^2}dr\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi}\cos\phi d\phi$$ But for the second, you'd better do a simple plot for $x$ and $z$ as follows:

[image]

According to our assumptions, $y$ is independent of other variables $x$ and $z$ since, $$y|_0^1$$  Now for $x$ and $z$ (see the plot) we have: $$x|_{0.5}^1,~~z|_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}},~~~~~~~~~~~x|_1^2,~~z|_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$$

Comment: how did you plot them? I tried in wolframalpha but it won't work. Anyway so the volume is then the sum of 2 triple integrals right?

Comment: The integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{r^2}{1+r^2}dr$$ diverges.

Comment: it's OK if it doesn't converge, @B.S. Is the answer $4*pi/6$?

Comment: @blondy Allright in that case.

Comment: @B.S. are you sure that's the plot. I get something else: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%3C%3Dx%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3C%3D4+and+0%3C%3Dz%3C%3Dx*sqrt%283%29 I get 1/6 of a ring not 1/6 of a circle.

Comment: @blondy: See the post plz.

Comment: ok so the answer is 1.845 thanks so much for helping.